# How to I enable Gradle configuration cache feature persistently?

Tags: gradle

Gradle has this new feature to cache configuration instead of recalculating it for every build.
It can be enabled on the command line with `--configuration-cache`, but how can it be enabled persistently in a file that I would check in source control?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Gradle *configuration* cache, available starting with Gradle 6.6, not to be confused with the Gradle *build* cache, is a feature that significantly improves build performance by caching the result of the configuration phase and reusing this for subsequent builds.

It is conceptually similar to the build cache, but caches different information. The build cache takes care of caching the outputs and intermediate files of the build, such as task outputs or artifact transform outputs. The configuration cache takes care of caching the build configuration for a particular set of tasks. In other words, the configuration cache caches the output of the configuration phase, and the build cache caches the outputs of the execution phase.

The configuration cache can be enabled from the command line:

```
❯ gradle --configuration-cache build
```

It can also be enabled persistently in a `gradle.properties` file that you can check into source control:

```
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true
```

or if you're on Gradle 8.1+ where the feature is stable:

```
org.gradle.configuration-cache=true
```

If it is enabled in a `gradle.properties` file, it can be disabled on the command line for one build invocation:

```
❯ gradle --no-configuration-cache build
```

See the official documentation for more command line and `gradle.properties` options:
https://docs.gradle.org/nightly/userguide/configuration_cache.html

Comment: Big warning: This switch can skip changes in the manifest, like, version code & name! Even a `Rebuild Project` or an `Invalidate Caches...` doesn't fix it. So need to either disable it or remember to rebuild / sync  your gradles when you change your manifest. (Took an unnecessary long time to find this.)

Comment: I received the gradle cache error. so if you received any type of error related to cache just check & make sure you have put org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=false